# How to use Fluent UI Icons on an intranet

Tags: reactjs, uikit, icons, fluentui-react

I made a react project using Fluent UI kit.

I have this code:

```
import { initializeIcons } from '@fluentui/font-icons-mdl2';

initializeIcons(undefined, { disableWarnings: true });
```

It works fine on my machine, but this project is deployed on an intranet, so icons don't display on user's machines, i noticed that there are requests for icons like this:

```
https://spoprod-a.akamaihd.net/files/fabric/assets/icons/fabric-icons-1-4d521695.woff
```

i would like to self-host this icons on my project.

how could i do that?

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this approach trough projects. The main idea is to use `CopyWebpackPlugin` to copy icons from `node_modules/@fluentui/font-icons-mdl2/fonts` to specific folder:

```
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin')
...
module.exports = {
  ...
  plugins: [
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{ from: 'node_modules/@fluentui/font-icons-mdl2/fonts', to: 'fabric-font' }]),
  ]
}
```

Change icon destination:

```
import { initializeIcons } from '@fluentui/font-icons-mdl2';

initializeIcons('/fabric-font/', { disableWarnings: true });
```

This [link](https://github.com/microsoft/fluentui/tree/master/packages/font-icons-mdl2) also might help.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, now I have the following problem:
```
downloadable font: rejected by sanitizer (font-family: "FabricMDL2Icons-2" style:normal weight:400 stretch:100 src index:0) source: http://localhost:3000/fabric-font/fabric-icons-2-63c99abf.woff
```

Comment: nevermind, i solved it. i put a wrong path. Thank you again.